# Latex put the figure then the text but I want the opposite order

Tags: positioning

I have the following code :

```
    \begin{figure}[h]
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/partie_2/module_S0_surf_10000}
   \caption{\label{module_S0} $|S_0|=f(\epsilon,\lambda)$.}
   \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{images/partie_2/argument_S0_surf_10000}
   \caption{\label{arg_S0} $Arg(S_0)=f(\epsilon,\lambda)$. Blablabla).}
\end{figure}

SOME TEXT HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERE
```

My problem is that latex first right "SOME TEXT HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEERE" **on a blank page** and then he puts my figure **on a blank page too**. So I know it is not a problem of spacing because both my text and my figures are alone on their pages. Latex just dont write things in the same order as I wrote the code.

Could you explain me why it does this ?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What happens if you replace `\begin{figure}[h]` with `\begin{figure}[h!]`?

Comment: For an in-depth discussion of how LaTeX places floats, see [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5001)

Comment: The only reason to put the image in `figure` is to allow latex to move it. using `[h]` severely restricts the places latex can place it, `[htp]` is a more reasonable option.

Comment: @cfr it's perfectly OK to have multiple captions and the right thing to do if you want two figures to float together

Comment: It should also be mentioned that you can use \captionof{figure} outside a figure environment.  This requires either the caption or captionof packages and is best when used in a minipage.